# meta information not being picked up by facebook

Tags: facebook, metadata, social-networking

I've asked this question on the facebook and ping.fm developer forums, but they don't seem to be very busy at the moment. So lets see what you lot can do...

I have included meta tags for title, description and image_src on my site so facebook can pick this information up and display it on users's posts on facebook. I am using ping.fm to make the post to facebook. The meta data appears to work fine on a 'pages' page on facebook, but on individual user's walls it doesn't show any of the meta data in the post.

Any ideas why this is?

I'm not really a facebook developer, but would like this to work so if there is something that I need to do let me know.

The link that is being posted to facebook is a ping.fm tinyurl, but as I said it works on 'pages'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it was actually a ping.fm setting in the users account which was preventing this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're sharing/posting this on Facebook, but maybe the [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) will help? Maybe you can share the URL for the page in question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share the URL of the page in question. However, when using the Linter, It extracts all the appropriate meta data without any problem.

Is there some sort of setting in the facebook account perhaps?